# Optimize mysql NOT IN query by using temporary variable

Tags: mysql

I was trying to optimize NOT IN clause in mysql: Some how I ended up in the following query:

```
SELECT @i:=(SELECT correct_option_word_id FROM sent_question WHERE msisdn='abc');
SELECT * FROM word WHERE  @i IS NULL OR word_id NOT IN (@i);
```

There is no relationship between `sent_question` table and `word` table. And also I cannot place index on `correct_option_word_id`.

Can somebody please explain, will this method even optimize the query or not?

**UPDATE**: As mentioned [here](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) that both the methods: NOT IN and LEFT JOIN/IS NULL are almost equally efficient. That's why I don't want to use LEFT JOIN/IS NULL method.

**UPDATE 2**:
Explain results for **original query**:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM word WHERE word_id NOT IN (SELECT correct_option_word_id FROM sent_question WHERE msisdn='abc');
+----+--------------------+---------------+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table         | type | possible_keys           | key                     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+---------------+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | word          | ALL  | NULL                    | NULL                    | NULL    | NULL  |   10 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | sent_question | ref  | fk_question_subscriber1 | fk_question_subscriber1 | 48      | const |    1 | Using where |
+----+--------------------+---------------+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: Is there a relationship between `sent_question` and `word`? What was the original query?

Comment: @MarcusAdams There is no relationship between `sent_question` table and `word` table. And also I cannot place index on `correct_option_word_id`.

Comment: Please show the `EXPLAIN` result for your original query.

Comment: Thanks for the explain. It looks like you don't have any indexes at all on the `word` table. Please check out my updated answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in that both the `NOT IN` and `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` method are [equally efficient](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/), however, unfortunately, there is no faster option, only slower ones (`NOT EXISTS`).

Here's your query, simplified:

```
SELECT *
FROM word
  WHERE
  word_id NOT IN (SELECT correct_option_word_id FROM sent_question WHERE msisdn='abc')
```

As you know, MySQL will do the subquery first and use the returned result set for the `NOT IN` clause. Then, it will scan through all of the rows in `word` to see if `word_id` is in the list for each row.

Unfortunately for this case, indexes are inclusive, not exclusive. They don't help with `NOT` queries. A [covering index](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/11/23/covering-index-and-prefix-indexes/) on `word` could potentially still be used to avoid accessing the actual table, and provide some IO benefits, but it won't be used in the traditional "lookup" sense. However, since you are returning all columns on the `word` table, it may not be viable to have such a large index.

The most important index that will be used here is an index on `sent_question.msisdn` for the subquery. Ensure that you have that index defined. A multi-column "covering" index on `(msisdn, correct_option_word_id)` would be best.

If you share your design, we can probably offer some design solutions for optimization.

Comment: I have added explain results for the original 'up-optimized' query, please have a look.

Comment: @djaqeel, thanks, I've updated my answer with more information. There's nothing seriously wrong with your query, but a covering index could help some.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am shying to ask "are dead you sure that my query exactly ends up like you mentioned"? I read somewhere that subquery in NOT IN clause executes for every row. Is it true?

Comment: The subquery would execute for each row if it referenced a column in the main query. In this case, it does NOT reference the main query, and therefore does NOT execute for each row.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it'll work at all.

Try

```
SELECT * 
FROM word  AS w
LEFT JOIN sent_question AS sq
ON w.word_id = sq.correct_option_word_id  AND sq.msisdn='abc'
WHERE sq.correct_option_word_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this simple query a try

```
SELECT 
    sent_question.*, 
    word.word_id AS foundWord
FROM sent_question 
LEFT JOIN word
    ON word.word_id = sent_question.correct_option_word_id

WHERE sent_question.msisdn='abc'

// GROUP BY sent_question.correct_option_word_id // This shouldn't be needed but included for completion
HAVING foundWord IS NULL
```